# Book where a mysterious force transports most of the humans from Earth to various other planets and times

Tags: story-identification, novel, science

I forget the title and author, but he described the opening as such: a mysterious force, likely aliens, removes a large proportion of humans from Earth, and transports them to different planets, while also going back in time by the same distance. I believe the main action of the book begins with communications arriving at earth simultaneously from each of these unwitting colonies at the same time, shortly after the abduction. 
Thank you.

Comment: This reminds me a little of the backstory from Charles Stross' Singularity Sky: http://www.nesfa.org/reviews/Olson/SingularitySky.html

Comment: @andrewsi Make it an answer, man. It's perfect. The setting is sometimes referred to as "the Eschaton universe" after the superhuman entity at play. Alas, Stross has said he won't be playing in that realm any more, so there is just *Singularity Sky* and *Iron Sunrise*.

Comment: I guess that was it. Didn't seem the same when I looked at the precis, but the backstory does fit. Thank you.

Comment: This has too few deatils, so I'm not sure, but can it be Philip José Farmer's *Riverworld*, or some book by A & B Strugatsky?

Comment: I'm not convinced it is _Singularity Sky_. Stross's main action doesn't begin on Earth, as I remember. Moreover, I think I've come across an earlier story which describes its setting in almost the same words brad uses. Trying to remember it now, I get the feel of John Varley, who sometimes invokes incredibly powerful aliens who stand outside Time, perceiving and manipulating it as though it were just another dimension of space. A good example is "Just Another Perfect Day", https://www.lightspeedmagazine.com/fiction/just-another-perfect-day/ . Search therein for "Flatland".

Comment: On second thoughts, or rather second actions, maybe it is "Singularity Sky". I found this, but in the middle of the book, not at the beginning:

Comment: "In the mid-22nd century, an exploration ship reached Barnard’s Star. Faint radio signals from the small second planet were decoded; the ship's crew learned what had happened to the people the Eschaton had removed. Scattered outside the terrestrial light cone, they’d been made involuntary colonists of thousands of worlds: exported through wormholes that led back in time as well as out in space, given a minimal support system of robot factories and an environment with breathable air. Some the inhabited worlds, close to Earth, had short histories, but farther out, many centuries had passed."

Comment: N.B. I shortened the text slightly to fit the comment limit, so it's not quite a verbatim quote.